# Scanning Maxicode in android?

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zxing

Zxing does not support UPS maxicode, Is there anyway i can implement maxicode scanning with zxing or any other solution?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It has a decoder, but not a detector; it will only read Maxicode in pure synthetic images. You can reuse the decoder, and finish it by writing a detector to find the barcode in the image first.

Comment: yea i have worked around with the decoder and its working fine with synthetic images, the main issue comes with detection. If you can pass any suggestions on detection it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. Barcode Scanner by Cognex Corporation (com.manateeworks.barcodescanners) (says it's based on Cognex Mobile Barcode SDK) has MaxiCode available in Settings → Symbology Settings → 2D, and I've had a success with it with.